How to use Tapir SttpClientInterpreter with sttp client 4?
Trying to upgrade this code to sttp client4:
SttpClientInterpreter().toRequest(endpoint, url).apply("foo")

it returns client3.Request[DecodeResult[Either[E, O]], R] even with 1.11.9 (which I think is the latest ATM).
Is there some way to make it give me client4 instead?

Don't think so. Sttp client 4 is not stable yet. https://github.com/softwaremill/tapir/blob/master/client/sttp-client/src/main/scala/sttp/tapir/client/sttp/SttpClientInterpreter.scala only expose for V3.

As @GaëlJ pointed, it's not possible yet. If you look at tapir build.sbt, there is no dependency on sttp client4. My guess is that you would need to change that dependency and build the project.
